# Jquery - fixed background color change in each section

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I have a fixed div that I am using as a background. I'm trying to change the color depending on which section of the page is in view.

Here's my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/4w9epnpw/

I currently am having trouble getting this to work when scrolling back up. I tried changing my if statements to be if height is > this div && < this div + the next div, but still having trouble.

I am trying to get this to work when scrolling back up and add a fade transition, any help.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var splashHeight = $('#splash').height();
var sec1height = $('#section1').height();
var sec2height = $('#section2').height();
if($(window).scrollTop() > splashHeight) {
    $('#background').addClass('redBg');
}
if ($(window).scrollTop() > sec1height + splashHeight){
    $('#background').removeClass('redBg')
    $('#background').addClass('blueBg')
}
if ($(window).scrollTop() > splashHeight + sec1height + sec2height){
    $('#background').removeClass('blueBg')
    $('#background').addClass('greenBg')
}
})
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Finally figured out the && to work the other way scrolling and began working on it. Still issues with the fade though. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Updated fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4w9epnpw/9/ new fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the Problem is that you just defined what happens when the value of  $(window).scrollTop() is bigger than the heights of the elements, but not what happens if scrolltop() becomes smaller

This should work:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var splashHeight = $('#splash').height();
    var sec1height = $('#section1').height();
    var sec2height = $('#section2').height();
    var scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrolltop < splashHeight) {
       $('#background').attr('class', ''); 
    } else
    if(scrolltop > splashHeight && scrolltop < sec1height + splashHeight) {
        $('#background').attr('class', '');
        $('#background').addClass('redBg');
    } else 
    if (scrolltop > sec1height + splashHeight && scrolltop < splashHeight + sec1height + sec2height){
        $('#background').attr('class', '');
        $('#background').addClass('blueBg')
    } else
    if (scrolltop > splashHeight + sec1height + sec2height){
        $('#background').attr('class', '');
        $('#background').addClass('greenBg')
    }
})
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogMGxP